# How to override the text displayed for a property in the PropertyGrid

Tags: c#, .net, propertygrid

Given a class like this:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public SomeClass()
    {
        Name = "Default";
        Values = Enumerable.Range(1,3).ToArray();
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int[] Values { get; set; }
}
```

A default instance of the class appears like this on a `PropertyGrid` control:
[image: PropertyGrid.SelectedObject = new SomeClass();]

Is it possible to override the text displayed for the `Values` property so it to displays something like `1, 2, 3` instead of `Int32[] Array`.

Solutions involving reflection and inheriting from the `PropertyGrid` control are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can add a `TypeConverter` attribute to `Values`:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(IntArrayToStringTypeConverter))]
public int[] Values { get; set; }
```

Then create a `IntArrayToStringTypeConverter` based on the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ayybcxe5.aspx). Not sure if there is already a type converter around that will do what you want.